# Как изменить Content Type в THTTPClient Delphi

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-xe

Пишу мобильное приложение под Android на Delphi 10. Моя программа отправляет post и get запросы использую компонент THTTPClient. Скрипт на сервере принимает запросы в формате json, по этому при отправке запроса нужно обязательно указать в заголовке "Content Type: application/json". Дело в том, что у меня не получается изменить Content Type. При отправке Get запроса он изменятся, а при отправке Post запроса - нет.
Использую примерно такой код:

```
procedure ThomeForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  data: TStringList;
  H: THTTPClient;
begin
  data := TStringList.Create;
  data.Add('{"phone":"' + HomeForm.Phone.Text + '"}');

  h := THTTPClient.Create;

  h.ContentType := 'application/json';
  h.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain, */*';

  log.Text := h.Post('https://site.ru/api/phone', data).ContentAsString();
end;
```

Почему такое происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: а если через `CustomHeaders` вписать? Между "принимает запросы json" и "нужно обязательно указать" связь "_поэтому_" не очень корректна. Обязанности в целом такой обычно нет, но сервер в целом может фильтровать запросы по сему заголовку.

Comment: Использовал CustomHeaders - не помогло, результат тот же. Сервер фильтрует запросы, и по этому в нужно в заголовке обязательно указать "Content Type: application/json".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `HttpClient` есть 4 перегруженных (overload) `Post` метода:

```
// Post a raw file without multipart info
function Post(
  const AURL: string; 
  const ASourceFile: string; 
  const AResponseContent: TStream = nil; 
  const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil
): IHTTPResponse; overload;

// Post TStrings values adding multipart info
function Post(
   const AURL: string; 
   const ASource: TStrings; 
   const AResponseContent: TStream = nil; 
   const AEncoding: TEncoding = nil; 
   const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil
): IHTTPResponse; overload;

// Post a stream without multipart info
function Post(
   const AURL: string; 
   const ASource: TStream; 
   const AResponseContent: TStream = nil;
   const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil
): IHTTPResponse; overload;

// Post a multipart form data object
function Post(
   const AURL: string; 
   const ASource: TMultipartFormData; 
   const AResponseContent: TStream = nil;
   const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil
): IHTTPResponse; overload;
```

Первый и третий методы отправляют данные как есть, второй метод (которым вы воспользовались) отправляет данные как `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, четвёртый метод отправляет данные как `multipart/form-data`.

Таким образом, вам нужно использовать первый или третий метод, если вы хотите отправлять сырые данные с указанием своего `Content-Type`.

Пример, с использованием третьего метода:

```
var
  data: TStringStream;
  H: THTTPClient;
begin
  data := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    data.WriteString('{"phone":"' + HomeForm.Phone.Text + '"}');

    h := THTTPClient.Create;
    try      
      h.ContentType := 'application/json';
      h.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain, */*';    
      log.Text := h.Post('https://site.ru/api/phone', data).ContentAsString();
    finally
      h.Free;
    end;
  finally
    data.Free;
  end;
end;
```